# Why does login_register not run after variable is met?

Tags: java, android

after using a runnable to show the progress bar has finished loading I declare the int visible to 1 and then have an if statement to say if visible =1 open new activity, but it doesn't work

I don't know what to try

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar myProgressBar1;//defines progress bar
    private TextView myLoadingText1;// defines my loading text
    private int myProgressStatus = 0;// defines status of the progress bar
    private Handler myHandler1 = new Handler();// adds a handler for the progress bar
    int visible;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome_screen);

        myProgressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);//Finds id of component
        myLoadingText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingComplete);//Finds id of component


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (myProgressStatus < 100){ //while progress bar value is under 100 add 1
                    myProgressStatus++;
                    android.os.SystemClock.sleep(50);
                    myHandler1.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            myProgressBar1.setProgress(myProgressStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
                myHandler1.post(new Runnable() { //call handler
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        myLoadingText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // sets loading complete to visible after time elapsed
                        visible = 1;
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
        if(visible ==1 ){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, login_register.class));
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is after the message "Loading complete" is shown and the int visible is set to 1 for the next activity to be shown, however, it stays on the first activity.

Comment: do you want to create a login session in your app ?

Comment: Yes in the next activity I will be doing that, this is the welcome screen which has a welcome message and progress bar and another message that becomes visible when loading is complete when this hidden message shows I want to move to the next activity but don't understand why it won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing your intent inside run() method.

```
myHandler1.post(new Runnable() { //call handler
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myLoadingText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // sets loading complete to visible after time elapsed
                visible = 1;
                startActivity(new Intent(this, login_register.class));
            }
        });
```

Your if statement has been executed first before the Thread has finished its execution.

Comment: Hi, I tried that before but I get the "cannot resolve constructor 'Intent" error

Comment: Try this. `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, login_register.class));`

Comment: Glad I could help. Anway could upvote my answer so that other's may know too? @BradleighJL